# Calculating a value to use in excel range

Tags: arrays, excel, reference, range, formula

I am trying to make an excel template so that when a user copies data into the tab "Account Profile", the last row with contents in it is calculated and this value is used for formulas on other sheets. This formula calculates the last row with data:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/('Account Data'!A:A<>""),ROW('Account Data'!A:A))
```

This works fine, the trouble comes when I try to use the result as a range reference: I want my formulas to iterate from row 2 --> row (value of LOOKUP)

```
=COUNTIF('Account Data'!$N$2:$N$991,A8)
```

The "991", I want that replaced with the result of the LOOKUP formula so that the range is always correct. I'm sure there's an easy way but I've tried for a while and can't figure out what the syntax should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott is right that you should just be using `COUNTIF` directly with a column reference. However, in case this is a contrived example or something, this is how you'd do it the way you described:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Account Data'!$N$2:$N$" & LOOKUP(2,1/('Account Data'!A:A<>""), ROW('Account Data'!A:A))), A8)
```

The important part to look at is `INDIRECT("'Account Data'!$N$2:$N$" & LAST_ROW_NUMBER)`. The `INDIRECT` function is how you take a string of text and interpret it as a cell reference. The `"Some text" & VARIABLE_NAME` is how you build such a text string from variables: you use the & symbol to concatenate them.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easier way to dynamically change the range of array functions or do you still have to use this workaround?

Comment: FWIW INDIRECT is a volatile function in that it will recalculate every time excel recalculates regardless if the data to which it refers changed or not.  Non-Volatile functions like INDEX/MATCH only recalculate when the underlying data changes.  What this means if you have one or two INDIRECT formulas you will not notice it, but if you fill a column with them it will slow down Excel's calc times. @MikeHawk

Comment: @MikeHawk What was wrong with dynamically changing them via Scott's method? It's fast, safe, and understandable. I was only answering your direct question, while he gave you a better alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

COUNTIF is not an array formula and as such you can use full column references without detriment.

```
=COUNTIF('Account Data'!$N:$N,A8)
```

But if you really want a dynamic range then use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=COUNTIF('Account Data'!N2:INDEX('Account Data'!N:N,MATCH(1E+99,'Account Data'!A:A)),A8)
```

This will find the last cell in column A that has a number.  If Column A is filled with text then replace `1E+99` with `"ZZZ"`.

If you want to use LOOKUP then:

```
=COUNTIF('Account Data'!N2:INDEX('Account Data'!N:N,LOOKUP(2,1/('Account Data'!A:A<>""),ROW('Account Data'!A:A))),A8)
```